# Laravel 5 & validating multiple email addresses in a single field

Tags: php, validation, email, laravel-5

I know in Laravel you can setup validation rules for input fields, for example:

```
    $return =  [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:300|min:3',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:300|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email,
    ];
```

Is there a way to easily set this kind of validation for a single field with comma separated email addresses (`test@email.com, wibble@test.com`) or do I need to manually validate these by splitting them apart and checking each email address individually?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this. You can (1) change your form to return an array of emails instead of a comma separated email list and then use [array validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#validating-arrays) (2) [create a custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) or (3) just do it manually using `filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` (where $var is each email in the CSV).

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
$rules = array(
            'email_addresses' => 'required',
            'email_addresses.*' => 'email'
        );

$messages = array(
            'email_addresses.required' => 'Email Addresses Required',
            'email_addresses.email' => ''
        );
```